How may source text have larger indent than the epigraph text?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.69\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\sourceflush}{flushleft}

\begin{document}
    

\epigraph{\justifying\emph{``Mathematics, rightly viewed, possesses not only 
truth, but supreme beauty — a beauty
 cold and austere, like that of sculpture, without appeal
 to any part of our weaker nature, without the gorgeous
 trappings of painting or music, yet sublimely pure, 
and capable of a stern perfection such as only the greatest
 art can show.''}}{\scriptsize Bertrand Russell in "The Study of
 Mathematics'', which appeared  in a 1907 collection, a 1910 book, 
and again in the first and second editions of 
Mysticism and Logic - 1917 and 1918.} 

\end{document}


Unfortunately I do not know how to phrase the question so as to include the following in the source text: "(\cite[31-44]{Russell1907}(33); \cite[71-86]{Russell1910}(73); \cite[58-73]{Russell1917}(60) and \cite[58-73]{Russell1918}(60))",
with recourse to
@article{Russell1907,
    author = {Russell, B.},
    title = {The Study of Mathematics},
    journaltitle = {The New Quarterly - a Review of Science and Literature},
    date = {1907},
    OPTtranslator = {translator},
    OPTannotator = {annotator},
    OPTcommentator = {commentator},
    OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
    OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
    OPTeditor = {editor},
    OPTeditora = {editora},
    OPTeditorb = {editorb},
    OPTeditorc = {editorc},
    OPTjournalsubtitle = {journalsubtitle},
    OPTissuetitle = {issuetitle},
    OPTissuesubtitle = {issuesubtitle},
    OPTlanguage = {language},
    OPToriglanguage = {origlanguage},
    OPTseries = {series},
    volume = {1},
    number = {1},
    OPTeid = {eid},
    OPTissue = {issue},
    OPTmonth = {Nov.},
    pages = {31-44},
    OPTversion = {version},
    OPTnote = {note},
    OPTissn = {issn},
    OPTaddendum = {addendum},
    OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
    OPTdoi = {doi},
    OPTeprint = {eprint},
    OPTeprintclass = {eprintclass},
    OPTeprinttype = {eprinttype},
    OPTurl = {url},
    OPTurldate = {urldate},
}


@book{Russell1910,
    author = {Russell, B.},
    title = {Philosophical Papers},
    date = {1910},
    OPTeditor = {editor},
    OPTeditora = {editora},
    OPTeditorb = {editorb},
    OPTeditorc = {editorc},
    OPTtranslator = {translator},
    OPTannotator = {annotator},
    OPTcommentator = {commentator},
    OPTintroduction = {introduction},
    OPTforeword = {foreword},
    OPTafterword = {afterword},
    OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
    OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
    OPTmaintitle = {maintitle},
    OPTmainsubtitle = {mainsubtitle},
    OPTmaintitleaddon = {maintitleaddon},
    OPTlanguage = {language},
    OPToriglanguage = {origlanguage},
    OPTvolume = {volume},
    OPTpart = {part},
    OPTedition = {edition},
    OPTvolumes = {volumes},
    OPTseries = {series},
    OPTnumber = {number},
    OPTnote = {note},
    publisher = {Longmans, Green \& Co.},
    location = {London},
    OPTisbn = {isbn},
    OPTchapter = {chapter},
    pages = {71-86},
    OPTpagetotal = {pagetotal},
    OPTaddendum = {addendum},
    OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
    OPTdoi = {doi},
    OPTeprint = {eprint},
    OPTeprintclass = {eprintclass},
    OPTeprinttype = {eprinttype},
    OPTurl = {url},
    OPTurldate = {urldate},
}


@book{Russell1917,
    author = {Russell, B.},
    title = {Mysticism and Logic},
    date = {1917},
    OPTeditor = {editor},
    OPTeditora = {editora},
    OPTeditorb = {editorb},
    OPTeditorc = {editorc},
    OPTtranslator = {translator},
    OPTannotator = {annotator},
    OPTcommentator = {commentator},
    OPTintroduction = {introduction},
    OPTforeword = {foreword},
    OPTafterword = {afterword},
    OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
    OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
    OPTmaintitle = {maintitle},
    OPTmainsubtitle = {mainsubtitle},
    OPTmaintitleaddon = {maintitleaddon},
    OPTlanguage = {language},
    OPToriglanguage = {origlanguage},
    OPTvolume = {volume},
    OPTpart = {part},
    OPTedition = {edition},
    OPTvolumes = {volumes},
    OPTseries = {series},
    OPTnumber = {number},
    OPTnote = {note},
    publisher = {George Allen \& Unwin},
    location = {London},
    OPTisbn = {isbn},
    chapter = {IV},
    pages = {58-73},
    OPTpagetotal = {pagetotal},
    OPTaddendum = {addendum},
    OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
    OPTdoi = {doi},
    OPTeprint = {eprint},
    OPTeprintclass = {eprintclass},
    OPTeprinttype = {eprinttype},
    OPTurl = {https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Mysticism_and_Logic_and_Other_Essays},
    OPTurldate = {20.08.2024},
}


@book{Russell1918,
    author = {Russell, B.},
    title = {Mysticism and Logic},
    date = {1918},
    OPTeditor = {editor},
    OPTeditora = {editora},
    OPTeditorb = {editorb},
    OPTeditorc = {editorc},
    OPTtranslator = {translator},
    OPTannotator = {annotator},
    OPTcommentator = {commentator},
    OPTintroduction = {introduction},
    OPTforeword = {foreword},
    OPTafterword = {afterword},
    OPTsubtitle = {subtitle},
    OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon},
    OPTmaintitle = {maintitle},
    OPTmainsubtitle = {mainsubtitle},
    OPTmaintitleaddon = {maintitleaddon},
    OPTlanguage = {language},
    OPToriglanguage = {origlanguage},
    OPTvolume = {volume},
    OPTpart = {part},
    OPTedition = {edition},
    OPTvolumes = {volumes},
    OPTseries = {series},
    OPTnumber = {number},
    OPTnote = {note},
    publisher = {Longmans, Green \& Co.},
    location = {London},
    OPTisbn = {isbn},
    chapter = {IV},
    pages = {58-73},
    OPTpagetotal = {pagetotal},
    OPTaddendum = {addendum},
    OPTpubstate = {pubstate},
    OPTdoi = {doi},
    OPTeprint = {eprint},
    OPTeprintclass = {eprintclass},
    OPTeprinttype = {eprinttype},
    OPTurl = {https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Mysticism_and_Logic_and_Other_Essays},
    OPTurldate = {20.08.2024},
}


@egreg Yes, it was screwed up. I think I rectified it by now.

What has “larger indent” to do with including the citations?

@egreg You got me there! It is another question.

@egreg I will split the inclusion of citations into another question

OK, let's try.
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Russell1907,
    author = {Russell, B.},
    title = {The Study of Mathematics},
    journaltitle = {The New Quarterly - a Review of Science and Literature},
    date = {1907},
    volume = {1},
    number = {1},
    pages = {31-44},
}

@book{Russell1910,
    author = {Russell, B.},
    title = {Philosophical Papers},
    date = {1910},
    publisher = {Longmans, Green \& Co.},
    location = {London},
    pages = {71-86},
}

@book{Russell1917,
    author = {Russell, B.},
    title = {Mysticism and Logic},
    date = {1917},
    publisher = {George Allen \& Unwin},
    location = {London},
    chapter = {IV},
    pages = {58-73},
}

@book{Russell1918,
    author = {Russell, B.},
    title = {Mysticism and Logic},
    date = {1918},
    publisher = {Longmans, Green \& Co.},
    location = {London},
    chapter = {IV},
    pages = {58-73},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@epitext}[1]{%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\epigraphwidth}\begin{\textflush} \itshape #1% added \itshape
%    \ifdim\epigraphrule>\z@ \@epirule \else \vspace*{1ex} \fi % <--- removed
  \end{\textflush}\end{minipage}}
\renewcommand{\@episource}[1]{%
  \hspace*{12pt}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimeval{\epigraphwidth-12pt}}
  \begin{\sourceflush}\scriptsize #1\end{\sourceflush}
  \end{minipage}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushepinormal}
\renewcommand{\sourceflush}{flushleft}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.69\textwidth}

\begin{document}
    

\epigraph{``Mathematics, rightly viewed, possesses not only 
truth, but supreme beauty — a beauty
 cold and austere, like that of sculpture, without appeal
 to any part of our weaker nature, without the gorgeous
 trappings of painting or music, yet sublimely pure, 
and capable of a stern perfection such as only the greatest
 art can show.''}{Bertrand Russell in ``The Study of
 Mathematics'', which appeared  in a 1907 collection, a 1910 book, 
and again in the first and second editions of 
Mysticism and Logic - 1917 and 1918 \cite[31-44]{Russell1907}(33); 
\cite[71-86]{Russell1910}(73); \cite[58-73]{Russell1917}(60) and 
\cite[58-73]{Russell1918}(60)}

\end{document}

I used filecontents* just to make the example self-contained.
Adapt 12pt to your liking. For the citations I used biblatex, you can also use the standard BibTeX, if you prefer.


That's very nice!
